# in PDF creation in android studio? how to break a long text to multiple lines

Tags: java, android-studio, pdf, document

I have an application to create PDF pages, but the line remains continuous and does not descend to another line , I need to reach more than one line I need to go down more than one line of text. I can type long and go down more than one line

It looks like this to me

[image]

I need it to be like this

[image]

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument();
PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(1190, 1684, 1).create();
PdfDocument.Page mypage1 = pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo);
Canvas canvas = mypage1.getCanvas();

TextPaint mTextPaint=new TextPaint();
mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

mTextPaint.setTextSize(32f);
String s = editText1.getText().toString() ;

int x = 1120, y=300;

for (String line:s.split("\n")){
    mypage1.getCanvas().drawText(line, x, y, mTextPaint);
    y+=mTextPaint.descent()-mTextPaint.ascent();
}

mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
mTextPaint.setTextSize(32f);
canvas.drawText(editText3.getText().toString(),595,1560,mTextPaint);
pdfDocument.finishPage(mypage1);

File file = activity.getExternalFilesDir("pdf");
File file1 = new File(file+"/","pdf.pdf");
save = file1;
try {
    pdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(file1));
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
pdfDocument.close();
```

I have an application to create PDF pages, but the line remains continuous and does not descend to another line , I need to reach more than one line I need to go down more than one line of text. I can type long and go down more than one line

Comment: Question not Itext related. Removed Itext tag.